# Query regarding memory management in C structures

Tags: c, struct, memory-management

Suppose there is a struct a with other structs as members

```
struct a {
struct b* b;
struct c* c;
};
struct a* a1;
```

Now I allocate memory dynamically to an object of a
`a1 = (struct a*) malloc(sizeof(a));`

Now I similarly create a new object of struct b
`struct b* b1 = (struct b*) malloc(sizeof(b));`

Now after some time in code I create a reference for b1 in a1

```
a1.b = b1;
b1 = NULL;
```

Later if I free a1, will the memory allocated to b1 also get freed?
`free(a1);`

Comment: The code does not make sense. `b1` is a struct and not a pointer so you cannot assign a `malloc` result to it. But in general no, `free` will not free memory of any embedded pointers. But your code is not real compilable code so it is difficult to say exactly what you intend (which are pointers and which are not).

Comment: For that matter, `struct b b1 = (struct b*) malloc(sizeof(b))` doesn't make sense either (and wouldn't compile for several reasons). And `free(a1);` is also nonsense; since `a1` isn't a pointer. If you have questions about code, use *real* code.

Comment: I would caution you not to use ambiguous terminology like "memory allocated to b1". That could mean the memory for holding `b1` itself or that could mean the memory that `b1` points to that was allocated in that call to `malloc`. It's very easy to confuse yourself. After `... b1 = malloc ...` We have two distinct chunks of memory here, one holding a pointer to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Later if I free a1, will the memory allocated to b1 also get freed

No it will not. The rules are very simple:

- Exactly one `free` for each `malloc` (assuming we do want to free memory)
- The address passed to `free` must be exactly what was returned by a previous `malloc`.

Here `malloc` of course applies also to any other allocation function such as `calloc`, `realloc`, etc. So in your example the required `free` calls are:

```
free(a1.b);
free(a1);
```